# Java Parallel arrays on finding two matching items

Tags: java, arrays, parallel-processing

So in school, we just learned arrays and we have a project on it. It is to make a parallel arrays on a students name, test average score, quiz average score, homework average score, and final average score. Also, we have to find the highest and lowest scores. I have the highest score figured out unless 2 students score the same high school, then it will only show one. Here are my methods :

```
public String getHighestScore(){
    double highScore = 0;
    String students = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < totalTests; i++){
        if(quarterAverages[i] > highScore){
            highScore = quarterAverages[i];
            students = names[i];
        }
    }
    return students;
}
```

This segment of code now works. I needed to make the greater than in the if statement a greater than or equal to and add name to the string instead of changing it to one name.

```
public String getHighestScore(){
    double highScore = 0;
    String students = "";
    for(int i = 0; i <= totalTests; i++){
        if(quarterAverages[i] >= highScore){
            highScore = quarterAverages[i];
            students += names[i] + " ";
        }
    }
    return students;
}
```

This one only outputs 1 student with the high score rather than 2. My question is how can I output multiple students with the same highscore.

Comment: And your question is what? Output multiple students if there's a tie?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Try to clearify on exactly what is your question - and what you're trying to achieve. You can do this by editing your question.

Comment: If you are trying to display all students that tied with high score then you need to change the `students = names[i]` to +=

Comment: @KevinMee Not quite. That will append names _every time_ a higher score is found while traversing the array.

Comment: you can return a String array instead of just one string, and that string array will contain each person with the highest score. So u can loop once to get the highest score like you are already, then loop again and check if any other students scores equal the highscore, and add them to the String array

Comment: Kevin Thank you very much. I had this in the first place but I did not have the greater than or equal to in the if statement. Thanks!

Comment: @Spyke See Ted Hopp's answer for the correct approach.

Comment: @Spyke check the answers provided, as pointed out there is an error in the logic of just using += because all higher values will get added but not always the highest!

Answer (score 2):

To return multiple names, you need to do a few things:

1. You should return a `List<String>` instead of a single `String` value. (Of course, the list will only have one element if there are no ties for the highest score.)
2. You need to check whether the `i`<sup>th</sup> score is tied with the current high score and add the name to the current list if it is.
3. When a new high score is detected, you need to clear the list of names (which are tied, but no longer the high score) and add the new high score name.

Something like this (untested) might do the trick:

```
public List<String> getHighestScore() {
    double highScore = 0;
    List<String> students = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < totalTests; i++){
        if(quarterAverages[i] >= highScore){
            if (quarterAverages[i] > highScore) {
                highScore = quarterAverages[i];
                students.clear();
            }
            students.add(names[i]);
        }
    }
    return students;
}
```

EDIT: Since you are just learning about arrays, you may not know about Java's `List` data structure. Here's a variation that returns a concatenation of all the names, separated by a delimiter:

```
public String getHighestScore() {
    double highScore = 0;
    String students = "";
    String delimiter = ", ";
    for(int i = 0; i < totalTests; i++){
        if(quarterAverages[i] >= highScore){
            if (quarterAverages[i] > highScore) {
                highScore = quarterAverages[i];
                students = "";
            } else if (students.length() > 0) {
                students += delimiter;
            }
            students += names[i];
        }
    }
    return students;
}
```

(This should, of course, be done with a `StringBuilder`, but I don't know that you've learned about that, either.)

P.S. Since this method returns the name(s) with the highest score, and not the highest score itself, I'd strongly suggest that you rename the method accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Buddy, given the amount of information and code you have provided, below is what best I can suggest. Idea to send a list of students instead of string containing one name.

```
public ArrayList<String> getHighestScore(){
    double highScore = 0;
    ArrayList<String> students = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < totalTests; i++){
        if(quarterAverages[i] > highScore){
            highScore = quarterAverages[i];
            students.add(names[i]);
        }
    }
    return students;
}
```

Comment: You are adding to the list _each time_ a higher score is found while traversing the list, not just those that tie the eventual high score.

Comment: @GriffeyDog good point. You could modify this method to check the list to make sure only the highest gets returned instead of the whole list

Answer (score 0):

Find the highest score first, then find the students who has the highest score.

```
public static String getHighestScore() {
    // First get the highest score
    double highScore = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < quarterAverages.length; i++) {
        if (quarterAverages[i] > highScore) {
            highScore = quarterAverages[i];
        }
    }

    // Now get the students with the highest score
    String students = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < quarterAverages.length; i++) {
        if (quarterAverages[i] == highScore) {
            students += names[i] + ", ";
        }
    }
    // Substring is to remove the ", " at the end.  That's what the -2 does.
    return students.substring(0, students.length() - 2);
}
```

### EDIT

Or you could just use one loop

```
public static String getHighestScore() {
    // First get the highest score
    double highScore = 0;
    String students = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < quarterAverages.length; i++) {
        if (quarterAverages[i] >= highScore) {
            if (quarterAverages[i] > highScore) {
                highScore = quarterAverages[i];
                students = "";
            }
            students += names[i] + ", ";
        }
    }
    // Substring is to remove the ", " at the end.  That's what the -2 does.        
    return students.substring(0, students.length() - 2);
}
```

Data

```
private String[] names = { "Chris", "John", "Joe" };
private double[] quarterAverages = { 100.0, 100.0, 99.0 };
```

Result:

```
Chris, John
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I will try my best to help you as far as I can with the information you gave us. 
Considering it's a school assignement, I guess you have to return a String and aren't allowed to use Lists and so on.

Also I'm assuming the following:

- The Array `names` contains the student names.
- You want to get the names of the students with the highest scores in your String. If there are several students with the same score (which is the highest), all students should be included in that String

Let's look at **your** first code snippet (not my proposed solution)

```
public String getHighestScore(){
    double highScore = 0;
    String students = "";
    for(int i = 0; i <= totalTests; i++){
        if(quarterAverages[i] >= highScore){
            highScore = quarterAverages[i];
            students += names[i] + " ";
        }
    }
    return students;
}
```

So let's say that now there is a student with the quaterAverage of 5 at Index 0 and a student with the quaterAverage of 6 at the Index 1.
Since you add something at the end of the String if the current quarter Average is higher, you would have the name of the student at index 0 (currently the highest score) and then the name of the student at index 1 (then the highest score). That isn't what you seem to be striiving for since you only want the names of the highest scoring people.

I would propose something like this:

```
public String getHighestScore(){
    double highScore = -1; //maybe the highest score is 0 
    String students = "";
    for(int i = 0; i <= totalTests; i++){
        if(quarterAverages[i] > highScore){
            highScore = quarterAverages[i];
            students = names[i];
        }
        else if(quarterAverages[i] == highScore){
            students += ", " + names[i];
        }
    }
    return students;
}
```

So now, each time we find a student with the same score as the current highest one, we add the name to the String. If we find a new Highest score we reset the String and go from there.

Comment: In case you are allowed to return something else, or work with lists or something please let us know so we can adjust our responses ! Also best of luck in your endavour with Java buddy !